# Simple Phone gap/jquery project got an error

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I'm new of phonegap and jquery

In the log cat i got this error:

03-09 18:46:56.170: D/CordovaLog(10139): http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js: Line 2 : Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on page prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'bindRemove'

this is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    app.initialize();
});



var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bind();
    },

    bind: function() {

        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.deviceready, false);
        $(".buttonConferma").on("tap", selezione.conferma);
    },

    deviceready: function() {
        app.start();
    },

    start: function() {


        }
    }
};

    var selezione = {
         conferma: function() {

             navigator.notification.alert("Confermato!");
            }
    }
```

and this is my html head imports:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dettagliEvento.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Any advice to resolve the error? other similar question had not helped

I forgot to say I get the error when I press on confirm button (.buttonConferma)

Comment: Have you tried to move `$(".buttonConferma").on(...)` into the `deviceready` method?

Comment: it was the same, but when I removed the href in the anchor it worked different

Comment: Well, try to completly remove `$(document).ready(...)` call and use `deviceready` event instead. As far as i rememver on mobile platform you have to use `deviceready` for initialization.